# Memory management for programmatically created viewControllers

Tags: iphone, memory, viewcontroller, addsubview

I realize that there are many questions similar to this one, but having looked through quite a bit of them, I still lack the confidence to know if what I'm doing is right.  I apologize if this question is redundant, however I'd really like to nail down whether what I'm doing isn't bad practice...

To briefly summarize, I'm making a tool-like application, just for my testing.  There is a UIToolbar on the bottom with a button.  In terms of behavior, when the user clicks the button, it will open up a small subview in the middle of the screen. Essentially, it's a settings subview, where the user can toggle some settings.  If the user clicks the toolbar button again, it should close up the settings subview.

Anyway, the code looks like this:

```
//Interface
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController;
}
@property(retain, nonatomic) SettingsViewController *settingsViewController;
```

And here is the implementation:

```
//Implementation
-(IBAction)changeSettings:(id)sender
{
    if(!settingsViewController)
    {
        settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil]; 

       //Do some stuff here with CGRect to put the subview in the center of the view

        [self.view addSubview:settingsViewController.view];
    }
    else
    {
        [settingsViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [settingsViewController release];
        [self setSettingsViewController:nil];
    }
}
```

Actually, right now with this code, it's crashing when I try to close the subview (as in, when the code gets to the else statement above, it crashes).

Looking at the above code, I figured the retains might look like this:

- @property retain on settingsViewController (retain is 1)
- after alloc on settingsViewController (retain is 2)
- after addSubview:settingsViewcontroller.view (retain is 3)

I think I'm doing something wrong here.  Or rather, I know I am, since it's crashing.

I really do hope this is an ok question to ask.  Essentially, I'd like to know how to handle a situation like this.  I am programmatically allocing a viewcontroller and also doing an addSubiew, but I'd like to keep a reference to the object, since I need it elsewhere in the code.  What would be the correct way to handle this?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are releasing the settingsViewController too many times.

```
if(!settingsViewController)
{
    settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
    // [settingsViewController retainCount] should now equal 1

    [self.view addSubview:settingsViewController.view];
}
else
{
    [settingsViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

    [settingsViewController release];
    // [settingsViewController retainCount] should now equal 0

    [self setSettingsViewController:nil];
    // [settingsViewController retainCount] should now equal -1. This is most
    // likely causing your crashes.
}
```

Use either

```
[settingsViewController release];
settingsViewController = nil
```

or use:

```
[self setSettingsViewController:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you!  However, I have a clarification to ask:

Prior to this line: settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];

Due to the @property(retain), wouldnt the retain count already be 1?  then following the alloc above, wouldn't the retain count become 2?

Comment: In this particular instance, you are not invoking the property when you allocate and initialize settingsViewController.  If you have used the line `self.settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];` you would be right, the retain count would be 2.  You are retaining your controller as if it were a normal ivar when allocating it, but treating it as both an ivar and a property when deallocating it.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize that about the self.settingsViewController.  If I may ask, which is the correct way to do things in this instance?  Should I do it as illustrated above, or something completely different?

Comment: It depends upon how you are using the property.  I typically manage the release manually from within the class unless I am using the setter method to automate additional tasks.